# A polynomial $\ f(x)$ has integer coefficients such that $\ f(0)$ and $\ f(1)$ are both odd numbers. Prove that $\ f(x) = 0$ has no integer solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let there be a  polynomial $\ f(x)$. It has integer coefficients such that $\ f(0)$ and $\ f(1)$ are both odd numbers. Prove that $\ f(x) = 0$ has no integer solutions.

Comment: duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/753423/115115 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/182593/115115